# Can "A game a few would play" be a valid structure?

Tags: sentence-structure, punctuation, quantifiers

This is a line in a "poem", but I have changed two words to "game" and "play" with preserving the sentence exact structure.

> Indeed, a game a few would play.

I have searched for this structure which would be (if it is written in general): [noun] + [quantifier] + [verb]. But found nothing similar.

Also, I want to know if it should take a certain punctuation mark between the noun and the quantifier. I think it may be a period as it appeared that there's no structure like that. However, it is only a small pause between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Indeed, a game a few would play" sounds fine.

Remember that "a few" means a small, but noteworthy number, sometimes representing an undetermined number from a larger group.

"Few", without the indefinite article, is used to mean *scarcely any*.

- "A game a few would play" then means that a small number of people would play it.
- "A game few would play" would mean a game that not many people engaged in.

As written, I would not insert any pauses other than the comma after "indeed".

Comment: Thank you, Astralbee, for this informative answer! I want it to mean that there is actually some people who would do that but they are very few (like nearly 1 person out of 10000).

Comment: @TasneemZH If you are trying to *maximise* the number even though it is small, say "a few". You would say "few" if you wanted to *minimise* it.

Comment: I want to state a _fact_, so no, "few" wouldn't work.