# Can "lot" stand without the article 'a' to mean "so much"?

Tags: prepositions, expressions, quantifiers

> Thank you for [...]. It means **lot**!
>
> Thank you for [...]. It means **a lot**!

Can the first sentence be used instead of the second one when wanting to give the word a different value than the one in its original version (as in the case with **[few/a few](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/210132)**)?

I'm aware that it can mean *the meaning of the word "lot" in its structure with no-article.*

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+few%2Cit+is+a+few&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20a%20few%3B%2Cc0) shows a less usage of **it is few** compared to **it is a few**, and it presents *kind of* similar [plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+lot%2Cit+is+a+lot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20lot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20a%20lot%3B%2Cc0) for **it is lot** and **it is a lot**, so does that mean it exists without the preceding article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is this:

**to mean a lot [to someone]. The idiomatic expression requires the a.** It does not mean so much without the a and is also not grammatical.

And **to mean a lot to someone** means the same thing as **to mean so much** [to someone].
To mean a lot or so much are **adverbs**. They modify the verb to mean.

**few and a few are adjectives**:

Few people [not many] like this movie. A few [some] people like this movie.

A few and few usually pair up with: there are,not: it is.

You would see: There are a few people here. or: There are few people here.

Comment: Thank you, Lambie, for providing this nice answer! Does "It means a lot" convey the same meaning of the idiomatic expression you have provided? And what about the results in Ngram regarding the [lot/a lot]? Why did it show that plot of the existence of such a phrase?

Comment: Yes, to mean a lot is: It means a lot to me [that you responded so politely].

Comment: It appeared that the result Ngrams showed about "it is lot" was about [the name Lot](https://www.behindthename.com/name/lot-1) since I didn't check the box of the "case sensitive" option.

Comment: @Tazneen ZH Well, that would be: It is Lot [...]. Anyway, many would disagree with me but I think whether something is idiomatic or not can only be seen in native speakers of any language. Cheers.

Comment: Lambie, yes, it should have been "...Lot", not "...lot" as such structure doesn't exist. But since I have searched about it specifically and didn't check the "case sensitive" box, Ngrams included the results of "..Lot". I didn't realize that until later after you had inserted your first reply.